# Remove gap between header (header img ?) and nav

Tags: html, css

helpers :) I have a gap between the header and the nav bar, this occurs on all pages except index.html. Please view the site here: danachapmanmassage.com. I have checked to see if I have any margins, padding, or borders are affecting it - didn't find any.

HTML

```
        <header>
                <img src='images/5for5.png' 
                alt='Special Offer: 5 massages for just $50 each! Available through January, 2015.'>
        </header>


        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='services.html'>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS main styles

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    }


    /* ============================================= Nav Styles ============================================= */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #AA893C, #806720, #E9D07C, #806720, #AA893C); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #AA893C, #806720, #E9D07C, #806720, #AA893C); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #AA893C, #806720, #E9D07C, #806720, #AA893C); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #AA893C, #806720, #E9D07C, #806720, #AA893C); /* Standard syntax */
    } 

nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }

nav li {
    width: 25%;
    padding-top: .75em;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    }

nav a {
    font-family: 'abeatbykairegular';
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

nav a:hover {
    color: #42210B;
    }
```

CSS page specific styles (for services.html)

```
header img {
    width: 100%;
    }

menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    }

menu ul {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 56%;
    }

menu li {
    width: 20%;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    }

menu a {
    font-family: 'abeatbykairegular';
    font-size: .85em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

menu a:hover {
    color: #42210B;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `styles2.css` file.

Starting on line 23 should look like this:

CSS:

```
header img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few ways of fixing this:

- in `img` set `display:block`

or

- in `img` set `vertical-align:bottom`

Here is an explanation for the gap:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

> Regarding CSS, an `<img>` is a replaced element. It has no baseline,
>   meaning, when used in an inline formatting context with
>   `vertical-align: baseline`, the bottom of the image will be posed on the
>   container's baseline.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the value of the `display` property on `<img>` elements, which is `inline` by default.

Inline elements, including `inline-block` ones, are treated like text by the browser's render engine (kinda). It means that your code formatting can affect how the your elements are shown.

Changing the header's image `display` property to `block` should do the trick in your case.

If you wanna read more about it and learn how to fight this issue on other occasions, there's this article by Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

**— FF**

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely check it out :)

Answer (score -1):

In CSS styles1.css change style as following

```
header {
    background-image: url("images/texture2.jpg");
    height: 55%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}
```